# Do simple math after click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `span` with `final-price` id like this :

```
<span id="final-price">
    5000
</span>
```

And I want to when I click on a button with `myButton` id the `final-price` content change to `6000`. What can I put instead of `???` in below code ?

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {
  $('#final-price'). ??? // final-price number + 1000 (or any number)
});
```

Comment: What jquery version you use?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `#` as selector fro `id`.

Updated based on comment from Tushar.

```js
$('#myButton').click(function () {
  $('#final-price').text(function(i, text){ 
    return +text + 1000;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="final-price">
  5000
</span>
<input type="button" value="Add" id="myButton">
```

Comment: `$('#final-price').text(function(i, text) { return +text + 1000; });`

Comment: @TakaapoPage can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make it 6000.

```
  $('#myButton').click(function () {
      $('#final-price').text('6000');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use engine and one line code:

```
this.win["final-price"].addValue(1000);
```

[Run the Demo](http://studio.holaverse.com/apprun.html?mode=preview&user_id=73&game_key=ce3748b7463346b3a36e05e95bce30ea&company_id=7)